# I am try to login with my bcrypt password from my old database with in laravel default auth function but its not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, bcrypt

I am trying to build a user management system with my existing database, where '*bcrypt*' function for password encryption.
I wanted to login with the user information of my old database. i connect my user table with model, but I can't login and don't get any error when i am trying to login with laravel default auth function.

then i use this

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
    }
```

Even after that, I can't login or get any error.

now how can i login with my existing user information from my old database, and also want ot use bcrypt for user registration.

**UPDATE**
i found this problem, after password matching when redirecting the home page then i see, i get null value  ( Auth::user() )  thats why i fetch this problem.

```
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }
```

but how can i store user information at login time

Comment: Show us your form.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ,i add login form code now with my question

Comment: you are not returning anything on failed authentication ... and `bcrypt` is the default hasher in Laravel

Comment: Auth::attempt() get data from users table but my table name is different(member_user), i define my table name in user model. 
how to can i define my table name on Auth::attempt() function ?

Comment: When you created your new app, does your APP_KEY into .env file are the same from both app. If it's not the same, the password encryption will not match.

Comment: @ElieMorin passwords are not **encrypted** they are hashed

Comment: @romansyed if you defined that on the Model then that is the table it is using

Comment: I resolve this issue, now I have another problem . After login when I redirect home page and try to get auth user all information  ( dd(Auth::user()) )then I get null value